# How to catch and wrap exceptions thrown by JTA when a container-managed-tx EJB commits?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb, eclipselink, jboss7.x

I'm struggling with a problem with an EJB3 class that manages a non-trivial data model. I have constraint validation exceptions being thrown when my container-managed transactional methods commit. I want to prevent them from being wrapped in `EJBException`, instead throwing a sane application exception that callers can handle.

To wrap it in a suitable application exception, I must be able to catch it. Most of the time a simple try/catch does the job because the validation exception is thrown from an `EntityManager` call I've made.

Unfortunately, some constraints are only checked at commit time. For example, violation of `@Size(min=1)` on a mapped collection is only caught when the container managed transaction commits, once it leaves my control at the end of my transactional method. I can't catch the exception thrown when validation fails and wrap it, so the container wraps it in a `javax.transaction.RollbackException` and wraps *that* in a cursed `EJBException`. The caller has to catch all `EJBException`s and go diving in the cause chain to try to find out if it's a validation issue, which is *really* not nice.

I'm working with container managed transactions, so my EJB looks like this:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER
class TheEJB {

    @Inject private EntityManager em;

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public methodOfInterest() throws AppValidationException {
       try {
           // For demonstration's sake create a situation that'll cause validation to
           // fail at commit-time here, like
           someEntity.getCollectionWithMinSize1().removeAll();
           em.merge(someEntity);
       } catch (ValidationException ex) {
           // Won't catch violations of @Size on collections or other
           // commit-time only validation exceptions
           throw new AppValidationException(ex);
       }
    }

}
```

... where `AppValidationException` is a checked exception or an unchecked exception annotated `@ApplicationException` so it doesn't get wrapped by EJB3.

Sometimes I can trigger an early constraint violation with an `EntityManager.flush()` and catch that, but not always. Even then, I'd *really* like to be able to trap database-level constraint violations thrown by deferred constraint checks at commit time too, and those will only *ever* arise when JTA commits.

Help?

---

**Already tried:**

**Bean managed transactions** would solve my problem by allowing me to trigger the commit within code I control. Unfortunately they aren't an option because bean managed transactions don't offer any equivalent of `TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW` - there's no way to suspend a transaction using BMT. One of the annoying oversights of JTA.

See:

- [Why we need JTA 2.0](http://blog.bitronix.be/2011/02/why-we-need-jta-2-0/)
- [Bean-Managed Transaction Suspension in J2EE](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2005/07/20/transactions.html) (don't do this!)

... but see answers for caveats and details.

`javax.validation.ValidationException` is a JDK exception; I can't modify it to add **an `@ApplicationException` annotation** to prevent wrapping. I can't subclass it to add the annotation; it's thrown by EclpiseLink, not my code. I'm not sure that marking it `@ApplicationException` would stop Arjuna (AS7's JTA impl) wrapping it in a `RollbackException` anyway.

I tried to use a **EJB3 interceptor** like this:

```
@AroundInvoke
protected Object exceptionFilter(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
    try {
        return ctx.proceed();
    } catch (ValidationException ex) {
        throw new SomeAppException(ex);
    }
}
```

... but it appears that interceptors fire *inside* JTA (which is sensible and usually desirable) so the exception I want to catch hasn't been thrown yet.

I guess what I want is to be able to define an exception filter that's applied **after** JTA does its thing. Any ideas?

---

I'm working with JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final and EclipseLink 2.4.0. EclipseLink is installed as a JBoss module as per [these instructions](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToUseEclipseLinkWithAS7), but that doesn't matter much for the issue at hand.

---

**UPDATE:** After more thought on this issue, I've realised that in addition to JSR330 validation exceptions, I really also need to be able to trap  [SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException.html) from the DB and [deadlock or serialization failure rollbacks with SQLSTATE 40P01 and 40001 respectively](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/errcodes-appendix.html). That's why an approach that just tries to make sure commit will never throw won't work well. Checked application exceptions can't be thrown through a JTA commit because the JTA interfaces naturally don't declare them, but unchecked `@ApplicationException` annotated exceptions should be able to be.

It seems that anywhere I can usefully catch an application exception I can also - albeit less prettily - catch an EJBException and delve inside it for the JTA exception and the underlying validation or JDBC exception, then do decision making based on that. Without an exception filter feature in JTA I'll probably have to.

Comment: For clarification before I attempt an answer: `ValidationException` is a third-party exception, you said?  Not from the `javax.validation.*` packages?

Comment: Sorry, poor phrasing. "An exception I didn't define in my code that I don't control and can't modify". `javax.validation.ValidationException`.

Comment: And one last question: proactive validation (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/Validator.html) is out of the question?  (I am supposing it is; that there is something about the way EclipseLink uses proxies or something that prevents this from working on JPA-provider-supplied collection classes.)

Comment: @LairdNelson Flushing the entity manager aggressively does the validation automatically. It won't help with database level constraints that throw [SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException.html) which I'd also like to handle, and I'm still seeing the odd case where ValidationExceptions make it through despite aggressive flushing and manual validation. I'm not sure why yet, but I'd like to be able to filter and wrap 'em.

Comment: I'm currently looking into using EclipseLink specific [exception handler/filters](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Configuring_a_Session_%28ELUG%29#How_to_Configure_an_Exception_Handler_Using_Java) to achieve it.

Comment: Can you clarify "there's no way to suspend a transaction using BMT"? An inbound transaction is automatically suspended when you invoke a method on a BMT EJB.

Comment: @bkail See this post: http://blog.bitronix.be/2011/02/why-we-need-jta-2-0/ and the comments on REQUIRES_NEW there. Have I misunderstood? From your comment it sounds like the CMT->BMT transition in a call into a BMT EJB always suspends the current container managed transaction, making BMT EJBs always effectively `REQUIRES_NEW`. Sounds like I need to read the spec some more. If that's so, then my problem remains in that I still have no control over commit-time exceptions with normal `REQUIRES` calls, but it's helpful for `REQUIRES_NEW`.

Comment: @bkail Thanks for the pointer, found what you were talking about in EJB 3.1 spec "13.6.1 Bean-Managed Transaction Demarcation" on pp365, quoted in added answer. Looks commonly misunderstood given the blog posts I've linked to. I think that'll provide the answer I need.

Comment: @CraigRinger I would say BMT is closer to `NOT_SUPPORTED` than `REQUIRES_NEW`.  Your answer explains the situation clearly, +1.

Comment: @bkail Thanks. I said like `REQUIRES_NEW` 'cos *if* you begin and commit a tx within a method of a stateless BMT EJB that's what it's like. If you *don't* create or commit a tx within a method of a stateless BMT EJB then yeah, it's just like `NOT_SUPPORTED`. I'm going to nag the Java EE tutorial folks to improve the [bean managed tx](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnciy.html) docs as they really don't touch on any of the important stuff.

Comment: Ah, sure, I can see that perspective.

Comment: You can use the XML descriptor to annotate code (Exceptions) that are not under your control (3rd party).

Comment: @jjmontes Per your related answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19568680/398670 .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't tried this. But I am guessing this should work.

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
class TheEJB {

    @Inject
    private TheEJB self;

    @Inject private EntityManager em;

    public methodOfInterest() throws AppValidationException {
       try {
           self.methodOfInterestImpl();
       } catch (ValidationException ex) {
           throw new AppValidationException(ex);
       }
    }

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public methodOfInterestImpl() throws AppValidationException {
        someEntity.getCollectionWithMinSize1().removeAll();
        em.merge(someEntity);
    }    
}
```

The container is expected to start a new transaction and commit **within** the `methodOfInterest`, therefore you should be able to catch the exception in the wrapper method.

Ps: The answer is updated based on the elegant idea provided by @LairdNelson...

Comment: It'd be nice if it did, but unfortunately AFAIK when an EJB calls its own methods they don't go through interception, JTA, etc; it's just a direct call. The `TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW` has no effect. I thought about a similar approach where I split the `REQUIRES_NEW` method into a separate helper EJB, but that's (a) ugly and (b) no help for handling `REQUIRES` methods where tx commit isn't immediate.

Comment: How about then wrapping an EJB with another EJB. This way it should intercept the calls.

Comment: Ohhh, sorry I missed the last part of your comment. But Then you should handle the validation exception either by an explicit flush, or at the point where your EJB is called. On the other hand i do not find this ugly personally cause one is the persistence layer much like a DAO the other outer one is business interface.

Comment: Add an `@Inject`ed `self` instance field of the same class/interface for self calls.  Then Hasan's solution should work.

Comment: @LairdNelson That's legal? I wondered about that, but this post http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/how_to_self_invoke_ejb and its comments seemed to suggest otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to try to help out @HasanCeylan . It's a complicated problem :S

Comment: @CraigRinger, yes, that's legal, and despite Adam's reservations a common idiom.

Answer (score 7):

There's a caveat to what I said about `REQUIRES_NEW` and BMT in the original question.

See the EJB 3.1 spec, section *13.6.1Bean-Managed Transaction Demarcation*, in *Container responsibilities*. It reads:

> The container must manage client invocations to an enterprise bean
>   instance with bean-managed transaction demarcation as follows. When a
>   client invokes a business method via one of the enterprise bean’s
>   client views, the *container suspends any transaction that may be
>   associated with the client request*. *If there is a transaction
>   associated with the instance* (this would happen if a stateful session
>   bean instance started the transaction in some previous business
>   method), *the container associates the method execution with this
>   transaction*. If there are interceptor methods associated with the bean
>   instances, these actions are taken before the interceptor methods are
>   invoked.

(italics mine). That's important, because it means that a BMT EJB doesn't inherit the JTA tx of a caller that has an associated container managed tx. Any current tx is *suspended*, so if a BMT EJB creates a tx it is a *new* transaction, and when it commits it commits only its transaction.

That means you can use a BMT EJB method that begins and commits a transaction as if it were effectively `REQUIRES_NEW` and do something like this:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
class TheEJB {

    @Inject private EntityManager em;

    @Resource private UserTransaction tx; 

    // Note: Any current container managed tx gets suspended at the entry
    // point to this method; it's effectively `REQUIRES_NEW`.
    // 
    public methodOfInterest() throws AppValidationException, SomeOtherAppException {
       try {
           tx.begin();
           // For demonstration's sake create a situation that'll cause validation to
           // fail at commit-time here, like
           someEntity.getCollectionWithMinSize1().removeAll();
           em.merge(someEntity);
           tx.commit();
       } catch (ValidationException ex) {
           throw new AppValidationException(ex);
       } catch (PersistenceException ex) {
           // Go grubbing in the exception for useful nested exceptions
           if (isConstraintViolation(ex)) {
               throw new AppValidationException(ex);
           } else {
               throw new SomeOtherAppException(ex);
           }
       }
    }

}
```

This puts the commit under my control. Where I don't need a transaction to span several calls across multiple different EJBs this allows me to handle all errors, including errors at commit time, within my code.

The [Java EE 6 tutorial page on bean managed transactions](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnciy.html) doesn't mention this, or anything else about how BMTs are called.

The talk about BMT not being able to simulate `REQUIRES_NEW` in the blogs I linked to is valid, just unclear. If you have a bean-managed transactional EJB you cannot suspend a transaction *that you begun* in order to begin another. A call to a separate helper EJB may suspend your tx and give you the equivalent of `REQUIRES_NEW` but I haven't tested yet.

---

The other half of the problem - cases where I need container managed transactions because I have work that must be done across several different EJBs and EJB methods - is solved by defensive coding.

Early eager flushing of the entity manager allows me to catch any validation errors that my JSR330 validation rules can find, so I just need to make sure they're complete and comprehensive so I never get any check constraint or integrity violation errors from the DB at commit time. I can't handle them cleanly so I need to really defensively avoid them.

Part of that defensive coding is:

- Heavy use of `javax.validation` annotations on entity fields, and use of `@AssertTrue` validation methods where that isn't enough.
- Validation constraints on collections, which I was delighted to see are supported. For example, I have an entity `A` with a collection of `B`. `A` must have *at least one* `B`, so I added a `@Size(min=1)` constraint to the collection of `B` where it's defined in `A`.
- Custom JSR330 validators. I've added several custom validators for things like Australian Business Numbers (ABNs) to make sure I never try to send an invalid one to the database and trigger a DB-level validation error.
- Early flushing of the entity manager with `EntityManager.flush()`. This forces validation to take place when it's under the control of your code, not later when JTA goes to commit the transaction.
- Entity-specific defensive code and logic in my EJB facade to make sure that situations that cannot be detected by JSR330 validation do not arise and cause commit to fail.
- Where practical, using `REQUIRES_NEW` methods to force early commit and allow me to handle failures within my EJBs, retry appropriately, etc. This sometimes requires a helper EJB to get around issues with self-calls to business methods.

I still can't gracefully handle and retry serialization failures or deadlocks like I could when I was using JDBC directly with Swing, so all this "help" from the container has put me a few steps backwards in some areas. It saves a *huge* amount of fiddly code and logic in other places, though.

Where those errors occur I've added a UI-framework level exception filter. It sees the `EJBException` wrapping the JTA `RollbackException` wrapping the `PersistenceException` wrapping the EclipseLink-specific exception wrapping the `PSQLException`, examines the SQLState, and makes decisions based on that. It's absurdly roundabout, but it works

Answer (score 2):

Setting [`eclipselink.exception-handler`](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.4/org/eclipse/persistence/config/PersistenceUnitProperties.html#EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS) property to point to an implementation of [`ExceptionHandler`](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.4/org/eclipse/persistence/exceptions/ExceptionHandler.html) looked promising, but didn't work out.

The JavaDoc for `ExceptionHandler` is ... bad ... so you'll want to look at the [test implementation](https://dev.eclipse.org/svnroot/rt/org.eclipse.persistence/tags/2.4.0/foundation/eclipselink.core.test/src/org/eclipse/persistence/testing/tests/feature/Handler.java) and the tests ([1](https://dev.eclipse.org/svnroot/rt/org.eclipse.persistence/tags/2.4.0/foundation/eclipselink.core.test/src/org/eclipse/persistence/testing/tests/feature/ExceptionHandlerTest1.java), [2](https://dev.eclipse.org/svnroot/rt/org.eclipse.persistence/tags/2.4.0/foundation/eclipselink.core.test/src/org/eclipse/persistence/testing/tests/feature/ExceptionHandlerTest2.java)) that use it. There's somewhat more useful documentation [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Introduction_to_EclipseLink_Sessions_%28ELUG%29#Exception_Handlers).

It seems difficult to use the exception filter to handle a few specific cases while leaving everything else unaffected. I wanted to trap `PSQLException`, check for SQLSTATE 23514 (`CHECK` constraint violation), throw a useful exception for that and otherwise not change anything. That doesn't look practical.

In the end I've dropped the idea and gone for bean managed transactions where possible (now that I properly understand how they work) and a defensive approach to prevent unwanted exceptions when using JTA container managed transactions.

Answer (score 2):

> javax.validation.ValidationException is a JDK exception; I can't
>   modify it to add an @ApplicationException annotation to prevent
>   wrapping

In addition to your answer: you can use the XML descriptor to annotate 3rd party classes as ApplicationException.

Comment: I'm no longer working with this (thankfully) but to help others who still are, any chance you can add a documentation link to that?

Comment: Using the deployment descriptor (ejb-jar.xml). "The rollback subelement of the
application-exception deployment descriptor element may be explicitly specified to override
the rollback value specified or defaulted by the ApplicationException annotation."  [JSR 220](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/ejb-3_0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/ejb-3_0-fr-spec-ejbcore.pdf)

Comment: And the [ejb-jar 3.1 Schema](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CFMQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com%2Fwebfolder%2Ftechnetwork%2Fjsc%2Fxml%2Fns%2Fjavaee%2Fejb-jar_3_1.xsd&ei=qulqUvafJ-qg4gTbuoD4CQ&usg=AFQjCNGdH2sjKHnNAmwnKGbFi4eY3vrE1w&sig2=5ztOdTlhQ1DDFyizOD1dxg&bvm=bv.55123115,d.bGE) here. Most of the elements are optional, to support deployment configuration augmentation. Search for "application-exception". Not the best doc, but I'm finding really difficult to find info on the web (seemed much easier in the pre-Oracle days).

Comment: Much appreciated. I hope it helps someone else out soon.